# Retrieve the object from dict to that it can easily be dumped via json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

How can I get it to print out like below in a pythonic like way (I could manually craft it but feel like there is a better pythonic way), was originally thinking I could use dict for this but with my limited python knowledge, I'm guessing their is an easier way.  My end goal is to create a json object via json.dumps()

Desired Result:

```
{'cars': [{'make': 'VW', 'model': 'Jetta'},{'make': 'BMW', 'model': 'X5'}], 'name': 'John Smith'}
```

Code:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.cars = []

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model

>>> p = Person()
>>> p.name = 'John Smith'
>>> p.cars.append(Car('VW', 'Jetta'))
>>> p.cars.append(Car('BMW' ,'X5'))

>>> p.__dict__
{'cars': [<__main__.Car object at 0x7fe5566e9490>, <__main__.Car object at 0x7fe5566e94d0>], 'name': 'John Smith'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `json.dumps()` method has a `default` keyword that lets you specify a method to convert unknown items to JSON. Make use of that:

```
def default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (Car, Person)):  # so if this is one of *your* objects
        return obj.__dict__             # turn it into a python dict

    raise TypeError                     # Sorry, don't know how to handle this
```

then use that for creating JSON:

```
json.dumps(p, default=default)
```

Result:

```
>>> json.dumps(p, default=default)
'{"cars": [{"make": "VW", "model": "Jetta"}, {"make": "BMW", "model": "X5"}], "name": "John Smith"}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the class Car:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{'make': %s, 'model': %s}" % (self.make, self.model)
```

EDIT:

You can also do:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.__dict__)
```

But it will print all the attributes.

EDIT2:

I didn't realise that your goal is to generate a JSON file using json.dumps(). In that case, you should use Martijn Pieters' approach.

Comment: This does not produce valid JSON; JSON needs `"` double quotes for strings, and your 'dictionary values' are not quoted *at all*.